# NSArray initialization with numbers

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

I was wondering how do I go about creating an `NSArray` with say numbers 1-100 to be used in a `UIPickerView`.

I know from other programming classes I could do:

```
int array[100];
for (int i=1, i<=100, i++)
   array[i]=i;
```

But I am not sure how to something equivalent with `NSArray`, instead of manually typing in all the values.  I searched it online and I saw someone did it with *calloc* and was unsure if that was the best method, or if I could wrap the int into a `NSNumber` somehow and have each `NSNumber` go into my array.  And if I was to do this procedure, would I then create a `NSMutableArray` and *addObject* each time running through the loop?  I want these values loaded whenever the user goes to the screen.

Comment: Just indent your code with atleast 4 spaces and it will become a code block.

Answer (score 6):

Either:

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray array];
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i ++ )
    array = [array arrayByAddingObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

[array retain];
```

Or:

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i ++ )
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

...should do what you want.  If this is something you're doing often, you may consider creating a category for constructing an array containing a range.

Comment: Don't forget to release the array in the second example, since you have allocked it. (For that matter, why retain it in the first example?)

Comment: Lacking context, I imagined a use case that required keeping it around.  But yes, in either case the result will need to be released at some point.

Comment: Careful using convenience constructors in loops.  The first example will create 100 temporary arrays, each larger than the last.

Comment: @Skirwan if you are planning on keeping the object around, use [[NSArray alloc] init] instead - less lines of code.

Comment: It would be nice to edit and note that the first option is inefficient, and expensive in terms of memory and cpu cycles. You actually allocate a new NSArray 100 times, to create an NSArray of 100 numbers.